# How to use Yii CArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii, cgridview

I am new to php and Yii and need some help regarding showing array in the webpage.

In the controller I open my e-mail inbox and iterate through the e-mails in inbox and build array with each e-mail address as key having values

```
if (array_key_exists($fromemail,$senders)) 
{ $senders[$fromemail]['rcount']++; }
else {
      $senders[$fromemail]['e-mail'] = $fromemail;
      $senders[$fromemail]['Name'] = $fromname;
      $senders[$fromemail]['rcount'] = 1;
     }
$model->top_senders = $senders;
$this->render('Step2',array('model'=>$model,));
```

Then in the view file of Step2 I want to show the data in CGridview

```
if (isset($model->top_senders))
{
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($model->top_senders);
$gridDataProvider->setData($model->top_senders);
$gridColumns = array(
    array('name'=>'e-mail', 'header'=>'E-mail','value' =>'$data->e-mail'),
    array('name'=>'rcount', 'header'=>'# of mails','value'=>'$data->rcount'),);

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array('dataProvider' => $gridDataProvider,'template' => "{items}",'columns'=>$gridColumns));
}
```

But I will get error during rendering of the table: **PHP notice Undefined offset: 0**

```
    /**
125      * Renders a data cell.
126      * @param integer $row the row number (zero-based)
127      */
128     public function renderDataCell($row)
129     {
130         $data=$this->grid->dataProvider->data[$row];
```

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have this same issue. I will update with an answer when I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should't add data to provider as follows: 
`$gridDataProvider->setData($model->top_senders);`

It added during initialization. You must be sure that the array has a key `id`, otherwise you need to specify it manually (it must be unique) as follows:

```
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($model->top_senders, array(
    'id'=>'Name',
));
```

You will also need to make sure that the array `$model->top_senders` has the following structure:

```
array(
    '0'=>array(...user data here),
    '1'=>array(...user data here),
    ...
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes everywhere I see in the examples that array contains rows where keys for each rows are 'id'. In my array top_senders the main keys are e-mail addresses which then point to record of name, e-mail and numberofemails counter. How do I convert my array into the one required by Yii? I guess just to write for loop?

Comment: You can set custom primary key in your array as I say above. Simply specify which element of the array will be the key as follows:
`$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($model->top_senders, array(
'id'=>'Email',
));`

Comment: This is wrong.  keyField specifies the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you `var_dump($gridDataProvider->data)` you'd notice there's no value for the 0th index in the array. This happens when you run some filter function on the array. Assuming there are 5 values in the filtered array, the filtered array would look something like this when `var_dump`'d.

```
array(5) {
    [1] => Object (Mailer) {…},
    [2] => Object (Mailer) {…},
    [4] => Object (Mailer) {…},
    [8] => Object (Mailer) {…},
    [9] => Object (Mailer) {…},
}
```

A filter operation on an array can leave the array looking like the above.

When the CGridView is trying to feed the view with data, it does it sequentially—this, I find, is a shortcoming in Yii and should be raised as an issue.

In order to fix this, use [PHP's `array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like so…

```
$properly_indexed_array = array_values($filtered_array);
```

This will copy the values of the filtered array into a new array. This is not the optimal solution in terms of memory. So far, I do not see any means in PHP other than this though.

You may then go ahead and set this as the data for your data provider like so…

```
$gridDataProvider->setData($properly_indexed_array);
```